# How to get Jenkins job to fail if phantomJS.exe call exits with an error

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, automated-tests, phantomjs

In a Jenkins job, I have a windows batch Command build step, which runs a test with phantomJS, like this:

[image: smoke]

How can I make the job fail, if inside smokeTest.js I exit phantom with an error, like this:

```
phantomJS.exit(1)
```

Comment: Doesn't that make the job fail as is? If not, try adding `exit 1` in the bat after calling phantomjs.exe, just to see if that makes the job fail always, as it should.

Comment: @hyde - that is what I was expecting, but it wasn't working. Hence this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins considers a job as "failed" if the return-code of any command-block
(like that 'ExecuteWindows batch command' above) is non-zero.

If it does not work for you in this case, it is probably because 'phantomjs.exe' returns '0' in any case
(can confirm this by echo-ing the ERRORLEVEL just after that command: `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` ).

If this is the case (i.e.: it returns '0' even when fails), you can handle it this way:

- Print a clear error-message to the console (or STDOUT - something that will show in the log of the Job)
- Use the **[Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** to catch that error-message and mark the build as 'Failed'.

Comment: Thanks Gonen - I solved the problem by printing 'failed' to the console as you suggest.